# DefaultValue in react-select

Tags: react-select

I am generating dynamic array and passing it to react-select default Value attribute but failing to do so. Here is my code:

```
//enter code here 
if (this.state.campaignDetail && this.state.campaignDetail.length) {
      var str = this.state.campaignDetail[0].jobLevel;
      var str_array = str.split(',');
      for (var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
        jobLevelArray.push({ 'value': str_array[i], 'label': str_array[i] });
      } this.setState({ jobLevelArray1:jobLevelArray });
      alert(JSON.stringify(jobLevelArray));
    }
//enter code here 
<Select 
     value={this.state.jobLevelArray1} 
      //defaultValue={this.state.jobLevelArray1}
       isMulti
        onChange={this.jobLevelhandleChange}                     
        options={this.state.jobLevelOptions} className="basic-multi-select" classNamePrefix="select" />
```

Comment: Off hand I see that you've applied the `jobLevelArray1` to your `value` prop, and not the `defaultValue`. Was this your intention?

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov is incorrect here, by the way. He may be thinking of an HTML `select`, where as the React-Select does take either an Object or an Array as it's `defaultValue`.